# GDAL Nuget Guide

Tags: c#, visual-studio, nuget, gdal

Some people in Gdal forum ask me to try the GDAL nuget package. May someone help me regarding how to use the GDAL nuget package at nuget.org and may i know it still need to set up just like use in C++?

Comment: Sorry, general software/tool questions are off-topic at Stack Overflow.

Comment: Any update for this issue? Have you resolved this issue? If not, would you please let me know the latest information about this issue?

Comment: @LeoLiu-MSFT it seem my VS2012 cant use the nuget package gdal cause it require nuget update 3.0 and above. So i just download the package from [GISInternal wbsite](https://www.gisinternals.com/) website and add reference to the VS2012. You then can try example from [here](https://svn.osgeo.org/gdal/trunk/gdal/swig/csharp/apps/). Also can refer [this](http://vipassanaandenvironmentalinformatics.blogspot.com/2013/03/getting-started-with-c-and-gdal.html).

Comment: @MohamadFathin, Yes, NuGet **3.3** or higher is requires.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> how to use the GDAL nuget package at nuget.org and may i know it still need to set up just like use in C++?

Right on your project, select `Manage NuGet Packages...`, switch to the `Browse` tab in the open window, type `gdal` in the search bar, then click `Install` button:

[image]

If you install `GDAL` to your project you will get the `.dll` file you need and NuGet also automatically create a `GdalConfiguration.cs` that you call into to initialize the GDAL paths before starting. The only thing to note is the packages are setup to automatically copy their appropriate GDAL libraries to your output build directory. If you need to deploy the application you'll have to do a bit of extra effort.

[image]

Besides, you do not need to set up just like use in C++. For some more details info, please check following threads:

[How do I install the GDAL bindings for C#/.NET 4.5.1?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/138184/how-do-i-install-the-gdal-bindings-for-c-net-4-5-1)

[Exception while using GDAL in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14353502/exception-while-using-gdal-in-c-sharp)

Hope this helps.

Comment: It seems that installing only GDAL is not enough anymore, so you also need to install GDAL.Core package. If the config file does not get created you can call Gdal.AllRegister() to get it to work quickly.

Comment: @gtu's comment is a useful breadcrumb.  However, my C# app is using .NET Framework 4.6, not .NET Core.  Thus, for me the additional thing to install from the NuGet Package Manager was GDAL.Native instead of GDAL.Core.