# Error on Deploying a C# Application with GDAL Bindings to AWS Lambda

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, gdal

I have a .net core 3.1 Application which I'm getting the error below after deploying it to AWS Lambda function. I had a similar error when debugging from Visual Studio but I resolved it by installing the required nuget packages GDAL and GDAL.Native as per the answer provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14353502/exception-while-using-gdal-in-c-sharp)

```
System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'OSGeo.GDAL.GdalPINVOKE' threw an exception.
 ---> System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'SWIGExceptionHelper' threw an exception.
 ---> System.DllNotFoundException: Unable to load shared library 'gdal_wrap' or one of its dependencies. In order to help diagnose loading problems, consider setting the LD_DEBUG environment variable: libgdal_wrap: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
   at OSGeo.GDAL.GdalPINVOKE.SWIGExceptionHelper.SWIGRegisterExceptionCallbacks_Gdal(ExceptionDelegate applicationDelegate, ExceptionDelegate arithmeticDelegate, ExceptionDelegate divideByZeroDelegate, ExceptionDelegate indexOutOfRangeDelegate, ExceptionDelegate invalidCastDelegate, ExceptionDelegate invalidOperationDelegate, ExceptionDelegate ioDelegate, ExceptionDelegate nullReferenceDelegate, ExceptionDelegate outOfMemoryDelegate, ExceptionDelegate overflowDelegate, ExceptionDelegate systemExceptionDelegate)
   at OSGeo.GDAL.GdalPINVOKE.SWIGExceptionHelper..cctor()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at OSGeo.GDAL.GdalPINVOKE.SWIGExceptionHelper..ctor()
   at OSGeo.GDAL.GdalPINVOKE..cctor()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at OSGeo.GDAL.GdalPINVOKE.GetConfigOption(String jarg1, String jarg2)
   at OSGeo.GDAL.Gdal.GetConfigOption(String pszKey, String pszDefault)
   at WMS.Columbia.GdalConfiguration..cctor()
```

Comment: were you able to find a solution for this?

Comment: @SantoshKaranam Didn't find a solution for Lambda, decided to go another route deployed the application in Windows EC2 instance running IIS

Comment: ok thanks, even i decided to use NTS(https://nettopologysuite.github.io/). I was generating shp files.